# Radio button использование в таблице

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите как правильно вывести radiobutton в таблице для каждой строки ?

В таком варианте отмечаются при выборе все сразу, мне же нужно не зависимо

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Название</th>
        <th>ПК</th>
        <th>ВМ</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
       <tbody v-for="(programm, int) in programms">
         <tr>
           <td>
             <span>{{ programm.name }}</span>
           </td>
           <td><input type="radio" id="pk" value="pk" v-model="typ"></td>
           <td><input type="radio" id="vm" value="vm" v-model="typ"></td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Переменная typ должна быть массивом

Comment: Не пойму как это сделать

Answer (score 3):

Переменная typ должна быть массивом.

```
data() {
  return {
    typ: []
  }
}
```

UPD.
Вам нужно добавить в ваш массив programms поле typ, которое будет v-model каждого обьекта

```
<td><input type="radio" id="pk" value="pk" v-model="programm.typ"></td>

data() {
  return {
    programms: [
      {
        typ: ''
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Указал что это массив, ничего не изменилось

Comment: обновил свой ответ